# Draw a shape inside a Map Box circle

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

We are using Map Box circles to draw the markers as we have big data to work with, but I cant seem to find any solution to draw shapes inside the circles.

The circle layer looks like this:

```
 map.addLayer({
      id: 'markers',
      type: 'circle',
      source: 'markers',
      paint: {
        'circle-color': ['get', 'color'],
        'circle-opacity': ['get', 'opacity'],
        'circle-radius': 5,
        'circle-stroke-width': 2,
        'circle-stroke-color': '#ffffff',
        'circle-stroke-opacity': ['get', 'opacity']
      }
    })
```

Is there a property which I can add to draw a custom shape inside within this single layer? Note, that we have to use the type of circle for the performance, images, markers, symbols will not work.

The only solution I could come up for this is to add a secondary layer on each circle with the shape which could be drawn from the data.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a secondary layer is the right solution. That's exactly how you build up styles, and in cases like this there is no particular downside.

Comment: Well it is actually, a big one. In order to make drags on the markers you will need to manage multiple layers to go with. Also to draw smth on top of the markers you would need a polygon or smth for drawing the shapes, but then the shape will not stay within the marker.. There are loads of issues by making overlapping layers, but from my research I think there is no other way

Comment: If you're using markers, you have an HTML element you can draw whatever you want inside.

Comment: No, html markers or symbols are off the list due to their performance limits